# What kind of UWP app to make for Windows camera filtering app?

Tags: windows, uwp, camera, virtual-camera

The idea is to create an app that can read any local camera device, filter it, then have a new camera "virtual device" other apps can use as input.
How can this be done with UWP?

Comment: Does my reply make sense?

Answer (score 0):

> How can this be done with UWP?

Only the first part of your requirements could be done in UWP apps - **can read any local camera device, filter it**. UWP could connect to the local camera for capturing photo and video. You could also modify the media content as you want. More information could be known here: [Camera - UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/camera).

But UWP apps are not able to send the camera to other apps as a virtual device. You might need to try other ways like win32 to achieve this.